# How long does it take to process a French working holiday visa?

Tags: visas, france, australian-citizens, working-holiday

I am an Australian, and I need a French Working Holiday visa starting October 16. I will be traveling from August 1 until then. Since I can only apply for the visa a maximum of 3 months before, I have booked an appointment for July 21st — which only leaves me 6 working days to get my passport back from processing.

How long does it take to process a French working holiday visa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The French Consulate web site says the working holiday visa takes an average of 2 weeks, but 1 week is generally ok. We have an applicant of our [Ski Jobs France](http://www.skijobsfrance.com.au/) program applying tomorrow, so will let you know the latest processing time. The quickest time this year has been 3 days, but it does vary.

Comment: Thanks for your help - let us know how it goes, I might run the gauntlet.

Comment: The French working holiday visa was issued in 4 days this week. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks mate - that gives me confidence, if they can turn mine around that quick I will be in the clear. I was going to give them an express post envelope to speed it up a little. How responsive do you think they would be to me asking if they could speed it up? would they take offence?